# Java Application on Docker (MySQL + Rabbit)

Tags: rabbitmq

I am making an REST API which has a POST method which accepts a String as JSON and then sends it over RabbitMQ Topic and then a consumer is converting into entity and saving into a MySQL db.
Everything is running fine locally, but my task is to upload it on Docker and to be run online.
When I try to change "localhost" in properties with container names my Maven build fails....
How can i fix that?

I am putting my .properties:

```
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/rabbit_messages?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=1234


spring.rabbitmq.host = 127.0.0.1
spring.rabbitmq.port = 5672
spring.rabbitmq.username = guest
spring.rabbitmq.password = guest
```

and my docker-compose:

```
version: '3'

services:
  my-app:
    container_name: myapp
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    links:
      - rabbitmq
      - mysql
    environment:
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:mysql://mysql:3307/rabbit_messages?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=root
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=1234
      - SPRING_RABBITMQ_HOST=rabbitmq
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq
      - mysql

  java:
    image: openjdk:latest
    container_name: openjdk

  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3-management
    container_name: rabbitmq
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"
      - "15672:15672"

  erlang:
    image: erlang:latest
    container_name: erlang

  mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    container_name: mysql
    ports:
      - "3307:3307"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=rabbit_messages
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=1234
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=1234
    restart: on-failure
```

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: @derpirscher how can I run my app fully on docker?

Comment: edited* it, sorry about that

Comment: what errors do you get ...

Comment: @derpirscher when i write docker-compose up it says green check "done" on all the images but when Spring app runs it gets `com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure`

Comment: you should add that information to the question. Sorry, I cannot help you with your particular problem. My hints are just to raise the quality of your question.

Comment: @george_dev1222 When you get the CommunicationsException failure? What command are you running?